# NameError using Rails, Sidekiq & Clockwork

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq, clockwork

Looking at the 'Example `clock.rb` file' [here](https://github.com/tomykaira/clockwork) in the documentation, you can see that my code follows the clockwork conventions (?) exactly. However, I'm getting this error that I can't seem to fix. I've tried pluralizing and singularizing different variables.

```
`<module:Clockwork>': uninitialized constant Clockwork::Event::Manager (NameError)
    from /Users/MightyMouse/Desktop/DevBootcamp/phase-3/medmento/config/clock.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/MightyMouse/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/clockwork-1.1.0/bin/clockwork:12:in `require'
    from /Users/MightyMouse/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/gems/clockwork-1.1.0/bin/clockwork:12:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/MightyMouse/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/bin/clockwork:23:in `load'
    from /Users/MightyMouse/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/bin/clockwork:23:in `<main>'
    from /Users/MightyMouse/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /Users/MightyMouse/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p598/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

Here's my `clock.rb` file:

```
require_relative "../config/boot"
require_relative "../config/environment"

require 'clockwork'
require 'clockwork/database_events'

module Clockwork



  Clockwork.manager = Event::Manager.new
  sync_database_events model: ClockworkEvent, every: 1.minute do |model_instance|

    TwilioWorker.perform_async
  end


end
```

Essentially, I'm hoping that Clockwork will (1) loop through each `model_instance` *as seen above*, (2) find the `frequency_quantity` and `frequency_period` (together, they make up the "time") through the database associations, and (3) invoke the `TwilioWorker` at the right "time".

I've tried replacing the block with the code below. When I run the `clock.rb`, I am able to get a phone call from Twilio:

```
every(1.minutes, "twilio_call.job") { TwilioWorker.perform_async }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the Clockwork gem module structure. If you're trying to reference this file: https://github.com/tomykaira/clockwork/blob/master/lib/clockwork/manager.rb
then you'll need to use

`Clockwork.manager = Manager.new`

(probably already the default)

instead of

`Clockwork.manager = Event::Manager.new`

because the Manager class is directly inside the Clockwork module (you probably started with

`Clockwork.manager = DatabaseEvents::Manager.new`

which is a different case because Manager refers to a different class inside the DatabaseEvents module inside the Clockwork module.